# How to get onclick to work in edited innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, innerhtml

So in a navigation javascript file, i have this, which has the *onclick* event attribute to load  a new page:

```
function NAVLOAD()  {
    // Runs when you load page.
    document.getElementById("main nav").innerHTML = '<table class = "navbar"><tr>'+
    '<th onclick = "goTo("main_page")"> Home </th>'+
    '<th onclick = "goTo("archive")"> Archive </th>'+
    '<th onclick = "goTo("about")"> About </th>'+
    '<th  onclick = "goTo("faq")"> FAQ </th>'+
    '<th  onclick = "goTo("fanart")"> Fanart! </th>'+
    '</tr>'+    
    '<tr><td class = "spacer"></td></tr></table>';
}

function goTo(page) {
    window.location.assign(""+page+".html");
}
```

And, the HTML code that uses this looks like this:

```
<html> <!-- Stuff -->
<body onload = "NAVLOAD();"> <div id = "main">
    <!-- Stuff -->

    <script src = "HTL_navigation_script.js"></script>
    <div id = "main nav" class = "comic"></div>
<!-- Some other stuff --> </body></html>
```

The navigation table displays correctly, but the link does nothing when I click on it! **However**, when I put the HTML seen in the *NAVLOAD()* function in my HTML file, and only import the *goTo()* method from file, the links do work! What is wrong here?

Comment: What is your reasoning for building a navigation menu with Javascript, and why are you using a table for it?

Comment: I have multiple pages with the same navigation bar, and the free web-hosting my school provides doesn't give SSI or PHP.

Comment: Is the navigation menu going to change often? If not, it would be a better idea to just hardcode the navigation into each page. Also, you shouldn't be using a table to structure the navigation, tables are for tabular data and should very seldom be used in this day and age. Typically, [unordered lists](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp) are used to structure navigation.

Comment: That said, the issue with your Javascript is that the `goTo()` function is out of scope.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make following correction in your JS File containing NAVLOAD() method.Change the quotes from double quotes(" ") to single quotes(' '), in order to do that you will have to add escape character ('\') as well.

```
function NAVLOAD()  {
    // Runs when you load page.
    document.getElementById("main nav").innerHTML = '<table class = "navbar"><tr>'+
    '<th onclick = "goTo(\'main_page\')"> Home </th>'+
    '<th onclick = "goTo(\'archive\')"> Archive </th>'+
    '<th onclick = "goTo(\'about\')"> About </th>'+
    '<th  onclick = "goTo(\'faq\')"> FAQ </th>'+
    '<th  onclick = "goTo(\'fanart\')"> Fanart! </th>'+
    '</tr>'+    
    '<tr><td class = "spacer"></td></tr></table>';
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Working on my local copy... Have you used Developer Tools..To debug the issue at your end ?